# Configuring the Open Session in View pattern

Tags: hibernate, grails, connection-pooling

The OPen Session In View Pattern means transactions starts as soon as Server side thread starts.  This means connections are taken from the pool for the entire execution of the thread.  This means that if you have 60 threads processing at the same times, you have taken 60 connections from your pool.  All this means you can run out of connections very easily and starve your pool. (see: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView)

Is there any configuration parameter I can give hibernate so that the connection is only open when a hibernate API is invoked?  This would shorten the time threads use db connections?

Comment: hmm the link that you provided shows another explanation to Open Session in View. Read "the problem", it talks about the need of the hibernate session in your JSP's. In Grails, they're GSP's (Groovy Server Pages), and the filter proposed already exists.

Comment: Thanks but if you are not using JSP / GSP and only using Ajax requests  from JaavScript this should not be a problem.

Comment: If you do ajax requests that render JSON no. But I think that your question is not about "open session in view", but the hibernate session life cycle.